# Matrices between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose there are two real vectors $n \times 1$ vectors $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_j$. We can find a vector along a line between $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{x}_j$, using the formula $\mathbf{x}_i$ + ($\mathbf{x}_j$ - $\mathbf{x}_i$)$t$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

Of course, I can do the same thing for real matrices $A_{n \times m}$ and $B_{n \times m}$ using the formula $A$ + ($B$ - $A$)$t$ for $t \in [0,1]$. However, this approach is equivalent to the approach above since it is equivalent to $vec(A) + (vec(B) - vec(A))t$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

**Question**: What options exist for computing a set of matrices that are "between" matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Are trying to preserve any kind of algebraic or geometric interpretation? If not you’re asking about parameterizing curves between two points in a vector space, correct?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure. I was just interested in the directions people would point me to as I may know it when I see it. I am thinking about situations where there is a spatial component associated with each matrix (i.e. A is a grayscale image of a triangle and B is a grayscale image of a square). If this is true, then I wonder what advantages and disadvantages are associated with the vec-based approach.